# Cannot remove markers from google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, onchange

The markers in my program just wont remove with the deleteMarkers() function

CSS:

```
 #map-canvas {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height:500px; width:750px;">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
<select class="form-control" name="dateSelect" id="dateSelect" onchange="dateSelect_Event();"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
var map; <--- global variables
var locations = [];
var lat_get = '';
var long_get = '';
var marker=[];
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: {lat: 7.072617, lng: 125.599494},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: 13,
      });
};

function deleteMarkers() {
      for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++ ) {
          marker[i].setMap(null);
      }
      marker.length = 0;
}

function dateSelect_Event() {
      deleteMarkers();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

      var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("location");
           locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                 var data = snapshot.val();
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: {
                        lat: parseFloat(data.latitude),
                        lng: parseFloat(data.longitude)
                      },
                      map: map
            });
            marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
                  return function(e) {
                  infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)); 
                  infowindow.open(map, this);
                  }
            }(data)));
                  marker.setMap(map);

      });

 }
```

Firebase:

```
-databaseName
    --location
        ---latitude
        ---longitude
```

I just use firebase to get the lat and long on every change of the html select option and it work perfectly. The problem this time is it can't delete the markers. Should I do the deleteMarkers differently?

Comment: `marker.length` is readonly. If you want to get rid of the contents of the array while keeping a reference to it, then `marker.splice(0)`.

Comment: Your question title implies you can't remove the markers, the first line in the body implies you can't get them to show, which is it?  Is the `locationsRef.on` function running?  Can you provide a [mcve] or samples of the data returned in the `snapshot` variable (or from `snapshot.val()` call)?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I wrote wrong. I now edited the question.

Comment: @StackSlave I tried `marker.splice(0)` but it shows an error `TypeError: marker.splice is not a function`

Comment: Within `dateSelect_Event` you reassign `marker` to a `new google.maps.Marker`. You want to `maker.push(yourGoogleMarker)`, if you plan on using an array to access the markers later.

Comment: @StackSlave Thank you so much! I did exactly as you said and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StackSlave's answer. I was able to successfully remove it by creating and pushing the `google_marker` to the global `marker` variable.

```
function dateSelect_Event() {
      deleteMarkers();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

      var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("location");
           locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                 var data = snapshot.val();
                 var google_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: {
                        lat: parseFloat(data.latitude),
                        lng: parseFloat(data.longitude)
                      },
                      map: map
            });
            google_marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
                  return function(e) {
                  infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6)); 
                  infowindow.open(map, this);
                  }
            }(data)));
                  marker.push(google_marker);
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
 }
```